# Solving an equation

Tags: trigonometry

Showing $\sqrt a + $$\sqrt {\cos(\sin a)} = 2$

I've attempted various manipulations (multiplying by one, squaring, etc.) but cannot find a way to solve for a. Anyone have an idea how I can approach this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't actually possible to solve for $a$, but we can do some simple fixed-point iteration:

$$\sqrt a=2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a)}\implies a=\left(2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a)}\right)^2$$

We rewrite this as

$$a_{n+1}=\left(2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a_n)}\right)^2$$

And start off with a guess $a_0=1$.

$$a_1=\left(2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a_0)}\right)^2=1.401115158$$

$$a_2=\left(2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a_1)}\right)^2=1.579572306$$

$$a_3=\left(2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a_2)}\right)^2=1.600036196$$

$$a_4=\left(2-\sqrt{\cos(\sin a_3)}\right)^2=1.599473216$$

And this sequence will approach the solution.  I would personally use this method if you lack an understanding of derivatives.  If you did have an understanding of derivatives, Newton's method would most likely work much better.

Comment: I liked this. +1

Comment: @AlanTuring I was actually unsure if it would actually converge, since it could've oscillated.  But everything turned out dandy.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is approximately $a = 1.5994958620742425268$, but is very unlikely to be expressible in closed form.   Numerical methods (e.g. Newton's method) work well.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of equation, there is no analytical solution (it is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$) and numerical methods should be used.

As Robert Israel already answered, Newton method could be the simplest to use considering $$f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{\cos (\sin (x))}-2$$ Starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, the method will updtae it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For the present case $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}-\frac{\sin (\sin (x)) \cos (x)}{2 \sqrt{\cos (\sin (x))}}$$ By inspection, we know that the root is between $0$ and $\pi$ since $f(0)=-1$ and $f(\pi)=\sqrt{\pi }-1$. So, let us start at the mid point $x_0=\frac \pi 2$.

Newton iterates will then be the following
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.5707963267948966192 \\
 1 & 1.5999566241894927879 \\
 2 & 1.5994959773991264235 \\
 3 & 1.5994958620742497549 \\
 4 & 1.5994958620742425268 
\end{array}
\right)$$
which the solution for twenty significant figures.

Comment: +1. Your answer is pretty fine. Bisection Method must be the recommended one because we know the 'bracketed interval'. At the end, we can 'polishes' the 'bisection root' with the Newton-Rapson Method.