# How to rearrange $y=\sin(x)+2x$ with $x$ as the subject?

Tags: trigonometry

How to rearrange

$$y=\sin(x)+2x$$

with $x$ as the subject?

Is this possible?

I'm struggling to work out how I should go about this.

I also tried putting it into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsin(x)%2B2x+solve+for+x) to check how it was worked out but it doesn't return a result.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082103/trigonometric-polynomial-equations-and-the-algebraic-nature-of-trig-functions

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Fair enough, guess not then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082103/trigonometric-polynomial-equations-and-the-algebraic-nature-of-trig-functions), it is generally impossible to solve for $x$ given a particular $y$, so I doubt you would have much luck solving for $x$ for general $y\in\mathbb Q$.  The only closed form solution for rational $y$ occurs at $(0,0)$...

One may, however, approximate the solution using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

Let us define $x_n$ as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\sin(x_n)+2x_n-y}{\cos(x_n)+2}$$

Then as $n\to\infty$, $x_n\to x$ is our solution.  For example, with $y=1$ and $x_0=0$, we get the following:

$x_1=0-\frac{\sin(0)+0-1}{\cos(0)+2}=\frac12$

$x_2=\frac12-\frac{\sin(1/2)+1-1}{\cos(1/2)+2}=0.335417790$

$x_3=0.335418032$

$x_4=0.335418032$

And thus we have our solution:

$$1\approx\sin(0.335418032)+2(0.335418032)$$

Comment: It's not true that the only closed form solution occurs at $(0,0)$.  For example, for $y = 2+\sin(1)$ the solution is obviously $x=1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I meant for $y\in\mathbb Q$, sorry.  For other $y$ with arguments about what is closed form and what is not, please make comments under the linked question (it would be most useful there)