# To calculate the Lipschitz constant.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define the function $$\mathbb{X} \times \mathbb{X} \ni (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y) := \begin{cases}\frac{A}{\pi}\frac{\sin{A(x-y)}}{A(x-y)}\,\, if \,\,x \neq y,\\ \frac{A}{\pi} \,\, \hspace{16.5mm}if \,\,x =y.\end{cases}$$ Here we can assume that $\mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact set and $A \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.  I want to find a Lipschitz constant $M$ for $f$ ?
Recall $M := \sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X} } ||\nabla f(x,y)||$.

The above query is a small part of a bigger problem (which I cannot reveal). Any ideas and thoughts on how to proceed will be appreciated, as I have been stuck at this point for quite some time.

Edits: What I have done:
Observe that $$\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X} } ||\nabla f(x,y)|| \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}A}{\pi}\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X}}\Bigg|\frac{cos{A(x-y)}}{x-y}\Bigg| + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X}}\Bigg|\frac{sin{A(x-y)}}{(x-y)^2}\Bigg|,$$
after calculating the gradient $\nabla f(x,y)$ of the function. From the preceding inequality I can get an estimate that depends on $x$ and $y$ which in turn will depend on $\mathbb{X}.$  I am asking whether it is possible to somehow solve the optimization problem $M := \sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X} } ||\nabla f(x,y)||$.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{X} $ ?

Comment: You can assume $\mathbb{X}$ to be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Point taken. Thanks a lot.

Comment: First recap that there is not THE Lipschitz constant but A Lipschitz constant. Any constant $L$ for which  it holds $$|f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2)| \le L|(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)|$$ is called Lipschitz constant. What's your problem of calculating $$\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X} } ||\nabla f(x,y)||$$ on your own?

Comment: @Gono Well I can only estimate the value of $\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{X}}||\nabla f(x,y)||$. Is it somehow possible to find the exact value?

Comment: Letting $$
g(x,y) := \frac{\sin(A(x-y))}{A(x-y)}
$$
it follows that $f(x,y) := \frac{A}{\pi}g(x,y)$. So
$$
\|\nabla g(x,y)\| = \frac{\sin(A(x-y)) - A(x-y)\cos(A(x-y))}{A(x-y)^2}.
$$
L:et $h:=x-y$. Then, we are interested in determining the supremum of
$$
h \mapsto \frac{\sin(Ah) - Ah\cos(Ah)}{Ah^2} \quad \text{for } h \neq 0, h \in \mathbb{X}.
$$
Then to determine the supremum, one could proceed in the following two steps:
1. Determine supremum of the function dependent on $h$
2. Show that the supremum of the norm of the gradient of $g$ lies on the diagonal.

Comment: @souvikd Why haven't you shown what you got, yet? Then it's easier to see where you're stuck. $M$ will depend on $\Bbb X$ somehow. Additionally your function is not well defined. What happens for $x=y$?

Comment: @Gono I have added some more remarks.

Comment: @Spaceman Thanks for the reply. I can infer point (2). However, your point (1) is where I got stuck.

Comment: @souvikd I see, and this is precisely the hard step. I'm not sure if is possible to find the explicit roots of the derivative of the $h$ function since this would rely on solving trig/poly problems, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082103/trigonometric-polynomial-equations-and-the-algebraic-nature-of-trig-functions.  Although, that doesn't mean that there is no hope. Best thing I can think of would be to represent the $h$ function as a series/product series and try to obtain a sharp upper bound (easier said than done)

Comment: @souvikd Alternatively, it may be useful to approach differently. For example, how about considering the Fourier transform of $g(h) = sin(h)/h$, and obtaining bounds for that, and then using some bound comparison between Fourier and real space to conclude

Comment: @Spaceman Thanks for the reply. I have tried something similar by representing the gradients by a polynomial, not very useful. Your second approach seems interesting. Let me try and let you know.